# Filtring a data by time without a date

Tags: r, date, datetime

I have a data frame with column "datetime" which consist data as integer. I want to filter it by time in this column, but without a date. So, for example from a data frame with column like this:

```
2020-02-04 00:00:01
2020-03-01 00:00:02
2020-03-02 00:01:01
2020-04-06 00:00:31
```

I want to have a data only from a time between 00:00:00 and 00:01:00, so:

```
2020-02-04 00:00:01
2020-03-01 00:00:02
2020-04-06 00:00:31
```

(or without date, after filtering I don't need this column)

I've tried used format():

```
df$datetime <- format(as.POSIXct(df$datetime), format("%H:%M:%S"))
```

But it replace every cell in column with 00:00:00.  I'll be grateful for any help :)

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to use grepl and filter since you need specific values.

```
y = data.frame(value = c("2020-02-04 00:00:01","2020-03-01 00:00:02", "2020-03-02 00:01:01","2020-04-06 00:00:31"))
filter(y, grepl(" 00:00:[0-9]*$", value))
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to extract the hours, minutes and seconds out into their own columns with `lubridate`. Then it's easy to filter.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
data %>% 
  mutate(Hour = hour(TimeStamp),
         Minute = minute(TimeStamp),
         Second = second(TimeStamp)) %>%
  dplyr::filter(Hour == 0 & (Minute == 0 | Minute == 1 & Second == 0))
            TimeStamp Hour Minute Second
1 2020-02-04 00:00:01    0      0      1
2 2020-03-01 00:00:02    0      0      2
3 2020-04-06 00:00:31    0      0     31
```

Comment: Thank You! I have no idea the solution is so simple

Comment: Unfortunately I got the following error: Warning in View :
  tz(): Don't know how to compute timezone for object of class factor; returning "UTC". This warning will become an error in the next major version of lubridate. The problem might be with the type of this column. It's intieger no POSIXct